# Discord music Bot with python

Tags: python, discord, bots

im making discord music bot and im having a error in this line of code.
invalid syntax (, line 40) its on
`if "entries" in data :`

````
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import youtube_dl

from random import choice

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ""

ytdl_format_options = {
   'format': 'bestaudio/best',
   'outtmpl' '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s'
   'restrictfilenames': True,
   'nocheckcertificate' : True,
   'ignoreerrors' : False,
   'logtostderr' : False,
   'quiet' : True,
   'no_warnings' : True,
   'default_search': 'auto',
   'source_address': '0.0.0.0' 
}
ffmpeg_options = {
   'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
   def __init__(self,source, *,data,volume=0.5):
       super().__init__(source,volume)

       self.data = data

       self.title = data.get('title')
       self.url = data.get('url')
   @classmethod 
   async def from_url(cls,url, *, loop=None, stream= False):
       loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
       data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not
       
       if "entries" in data :

           data = data['entries'][0]

       filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
       return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename,**ffmpeg_options),data = data)```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you copy-paste the actual error you're getting, as well as a little description of what you expect your code to do? That will help us help you.

Comment: Please paste the error you are facing. That will help others figure out the kind of problem you are facing...

Comment: i did paste the error here it is : {invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 40)